# Bash function is not recognized when sourced from TCL interpreter

Tags: bash, function, shell, tcl

I'm trying to source bash file so I can use its functions from a different program written in TCL.

I'm currently attempting the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
function fun {
    echo "in fun function"
}
```

but when I source it, I get

```
function: command not found
in fun function
}: command not found
```

what is the issue ?

I tried all functions definitions: function  [()] { }...
how can I fix this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain how you source it (the exact command, and in which context it is used)?  This function works for for me after sourcing it from a script file.

Comment: I tried: source file.bash and source ./file.bash

Comment: Sourcing a file is not supposed to execute the function that is inside.  Is the code above all that you have in your script?

Comment: What seems to be happening is your "function" declaration line is being interpreted as a command (not a function declaration), and then the `echo "in fun function"` line is executed not from actually inside a function, but as a separate line following the one that fails, and finally the closing brace is seen as an invalid command, not as the closing brace of your function.  What Bash version are you using?

Comment: `function` is a bashism. If your outer shell isn't bash or another ksh derivative, it won't work. Use POSIX-standard function syntax instead: `fun() { echo "in fun function"; }`

Comment: ...so, if the outer shell -- the one that sources your script -- was run with `sh yourscript` or starting with `#!/bin/sh`, then it's *not actually bash*, so bash-only functionality isn't available. In this case, since the `function` keyword has no benefits over the standardized functionality (unlike other bashisms that actually add value), you shouldn't be using it anyhow.

Comment: @Saeedisa, ...if you're still having trouble even after implementing Fred's suggestion, we should probably look at hidden/unprintable characters in your script. If it's a DOS text file instead of a UNIX file, for instance, then your `{` could instead be `$'{\r'`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you know of any reason why someone added the `function` bashism (even if that reason is not really convincing)?  It seems odd to me that someone would invest time to introduce non-compatible syntax to duplicate something that already exists while bringing strictly no benefit.  It is not even shorter.

Comment: @Fred, ...if memory serves, in early ksh `function` actually had slightly different semantics than POSIX declarations did. I don't remember the details, though -- would need to look them up. In short, though, we're stuck with backwards-compatibility cruft.

Comment: (I almost want to say some shells allowed dashes in function names when using the `function` syntax, whereas the POSIX spec indicates them as impermissible; having an alternate syntax that allows dashes means you can shadow/override external commands with dash-containing names. But that's from memory, and I rightly don't trust my memory very far).

Comment: @Fred, I want to call it after sourcing the file, it happening as you described above, I'm using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)

Comment: @Saeedisa, can we check for DOS newlines in your file? Does `file ./file.bash` describe it as `with CRLF line terminators` or similar? If so, does running `dos2unix` fix it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I tried your suggestion, its not working for me, I'm using only linux

Comment: @Saeedisa, the question isn't so much about what OS you're using, but about the tools you used to create the file -- it's possible to have DOS newlines on a Linux system.

Comment: @Saeedisa, ...anyhow, could you provide the output of `bash -x file.bash`? The *exact* details of the error messages would be useful.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and when using your suggestion it says Badly placed ()'s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134604/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-saeed-isa).

Comment: Bash and tcl are different incompatible languages. You could just as well try to source a Haskell program or a French text.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll have to do in Tcl is to launch a bash shell in which you source the file and then call the function:

```
set bash_function_file "./func.sh"
exec bash -c "source $bash_function_file && fun"
```

Comment: that looks very close to what I did, after the guys help I have used exec command to with the specific file from tcl, that worked, Thanks alot